# Exporting JPEG after creating a list?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

I am utilizing ArcGIS Pro and ArcPy to automate exporting of JPEGs from several counties in Texas. I am querying each county, and attempting to export each. 
My script works fine when I run it in two separate part, but if I attempt to run them as one script only the basemap is exported, and not the polygons. See below.

```py
import arcpy
import os

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = m.listLayers("myselection")[0]
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("mapframe_element")[0]

county_names = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('myselection','NAME') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        county_names.append(row[0])

    del cursor, row
```

```py
for county in county_names:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myselection", "NEW_SELECTION", "NAME = " + "'" + county + "'")
    mf.zoomToAllLayers()
    mf.camera.scale *= 1.1
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myselection", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
    lyr.definitionQuery = "NAME = " + "'" + county + "'"
    lyr.visible = True
    mf.exportToJPEG(path + county, resolution=300)
    lyr.definitionQuery = ""
```

Comment: Once you run as one script, is the number of the outputs and the extent (of the basemaps) correct (must be equal to len of `county_name` list)? You can try printing `county_name` list before export to see if it gotten populated correctly. What happens if you change `mf.zoomToAllLayers()` to `mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent("myselection", True))`?

Comment: @fatih_dur the county_name list populated correctly. Also, I changed made the second, but I had to change "myselection" to lyr for it to run. That still did not fix the problem though.